# power shell to move specific files

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yfZk.jpg)
I have a list with users IDs in a txt file and a folder that contains a lot of files and folders with the user's IDs in the filename. I am trying to create a script that will look for each user's ID from the txt file, find the file that containing the user IDs in the folder with all files and move the matching ones in EXPORTED folder named by the full folder or filename that has been found in.
The filenames contains first name, last name and user id

I tried this one below, but this only moves  the folder only with the exact user id from the txt file... It doesnt move the files/folders that contains the user id in the list of files

```
$aryfiles = Get-Content "e:\new\text.txt" 
$sourcedir = "e:\new\" 
$destinationDir = "e:\new\new" 
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -Include $aryfiles | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 
foreach ($sourceFile in $SourceFiles) { 
    Move-Item $sourcefile -Destination $destinationDir 
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details. Include the script you've written so far, some sample data, desired result and actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a wildcard in the filter you use for `Get-ChildItem`. Create a new list with wildcards and use this list for `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$NewAryFiles = $aryfiles  | foreach {"*$_*"}
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -Include $NewAryFiles | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

To create a folder with the Name of the userID use `New-Item`. `New-Item` creates an output that you can catch to use the new generated folder.

```
$aryfiles  | foreach {
    $SourceFile  = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -filter "*$_*"
    $NewFolder = New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $destinationDir -Name $_
    foreach ($File in $SourceFile) {
        Move-Item -Path $($File.FullName) -Destination $NewFolder
    }
}
```

Comment: May i ask one more thing.. lets say in the same file with user ID`s, i add Firstname and Lastname... so it looks for at least 2 things, ether first name and id or lastname and id, and when found in the filenames, to move them same as now, but to add the corresponding firstname and lastname? 
The whole idea is i have a folder with bunch files of employees including their first name lastname and user id in the filename. i just want to sort them out in a new folder, named like, FirstName, LastName UserID :)

Comment: Jep that is possible. But I would suggest a .CSV file in this case. Its a table and powershell can use the headers of each column to work with. The `get-ChildItem` that creates the `$SourceFile` would need a  `| where {...}` instead of the `-filter` that matches the `$_.Name` with each of the headers. However since csv are a whole new chapter, I woud recommend you to test it a little and maybe create a new question.